# Non-Uniform List of items TractSQL, how can create a table that handles this data?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

To keep it simple I have Users and Skills. Skills could be like being able to speak Spanish or play football. It would not make sense for me to list all of the Skills possible. How can I address this issue?

Ex:

```
UID  Name  Skill 
  1  Tom   Football  Soccer  Baseball   Math
  2  Bob   Spanish   Band
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a table with one row per user and per skill.  This might look like:

```
create table UserSkills (
    UserSkillsId int . . .,
    UserId int not null references Users(UserId),
    SKill varchar(255)
);
```

Of course, `Skill` might also be a foreign key reference to a `Skills` table.

The key idea is that you need a second table to store the lists; you don't want to store lists in a single column or even in a single row of another table.

Comment: I kept it simple intentionally. I will have to have multiple foriegn key's in the Skills table, because my application requires that I keep track of the skills that changes from day to day so I will have to keep track of the instanceUID and the userUID.